# How to draw underbraces in `NiceMatrix`?

Tags: math-mode, nicematrix, underbrace

I would like to draw underbraces for some parts of equations which may be done easily with `\underbrace`

[image]

Looking carefully at the image above shows the underbraces are not properly aligned. Also, it would be better to be able to write the equation then write the underbraces contents. Thus, I use `array` package which also produces the very similar result

[image]

My questions about `NiceMatrix`

1. How to draw thick horizontal underbraces under certain parts of equations?
2. What is the simplest way to emphasize important equations by putting them in a box of customizable color, width, and separation from main contents?

My MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\underbraceX}[2]{\underbrace{\color{\colorMathTextDisplayed}\medspace #1 \medspace}_{
    \parbox[c]{\widthof{$\medspace #1 \medspace$}}{\hspace*{\fill} #2 \hspace*{\fill}}
                                                                }
                            }

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, LGRgreek, symbolre]{mathastext}

\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=SpringGreen3}
\newcommand{\colorInlinedMath}{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}\sisetup{color=SpringGreen3}}
\newcommand{\colorMathTextDisplayed}{black}

\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=black}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{empheq}{\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=black}}
\AtEndEnvironment{array}{\\[-4.2mm]}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\adjustboxMath}[1]{\adjustbox{cframe=black 0.141mm 1.06mm 0mm}{$#1$}} % (good values cframe=black 0.141mm 1.06mm 0mm)

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{frame}
    
    \begin{empheq}[box=\adjustboxMath]{equation}
        \underbraceX{\qquad Z\angle\theta_{z} \qquad}{Polar Form} = \underbraceX{\qquad\: R \pm j X \qquad\:}{Rectangular Form}
    \end{empheq}
    
    \begin{equation}
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0mm}
    \adjustboxMath{
        \begin{array}{c >{{}}c<{{}} c}
            Z\angle\theta_{z} & = & R \pm j X
        \\[-4.2mm]
            \underbraceX{\qquad \hphantom{Z\angle\theta_{z}} \qquad}{Polar Form} & \mathrel{\phantom{=}} & \underbraceX{\qquad \hphantom{R \pm j X} \qquad}{Rectangular Form}
        \end{array}
    }
    \end{equation}

\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The misalignment (vertically) of the `\underbrace`s stems from the difference in depth of the equations: `j` dips lower than the subscript `z`. If you just add a `\mathstrut` (or `\strut`) inside your equations and `\strut` inside the `\underbrace` text, things would line up properly and there's no need to use other constructions like `array` or `NiceMatrix`.

Comment: @Werner. This works well, but the idea is to write an equation in one row **then** add braces and description in another row. This is because entering both sides of the equations by along with their description using the traditional `equation` environment is redundant. I would rather go for `array` because when I need to copy such equation later on (excluding the description below it), I would simply need to copy the first row of `array` rather than copying the entire `\underbraceX` and removing the extra contents later on

Comment: **Off-topic**: Why do you use `\angle` instead of the command `\phase` of the package `steinmetz` done by @egreg?